# iOS AVFoundation select specific USB input

Tags: ios, usb, avfoundation, recording

I was using EZAudio for connection my recording interface

And I buy an used Apogee Quartet , it has MFi certificate

So I run the [project](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio)

I can select the quartet as input source

But nothing received

And Quartet has 4 analog inputs , How can select specific input ???

Thanks for any answer or reply

Comment: I forgot to add some info , You might need add "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" in the app plist